# Get arbitrary number of random elements from a php array in one line

Tags: php, arrays, random-access

I wanted to pull an arbitrary number of random elements from an array in php. I see that the `array_rand()` function pulls an arbitrary number of random *keys* from an array. All the examples I found online showed then using a key reference to get the actual values from the array, e.g.

```
$random_elements = array();
$random_keys = array_rand($source_array);
foreach ( $random_keys as $random_key ) {
  $random_elements[] = $source_array[$random_key];
}
```

That seemed cumbersome to me; I was thinking I could do it more concisely. I would need either a function that plain-out returned random elements, instead of keys, or one that could convert keys to elements, so I could do something like this:

```
$random_elements = keys_to_elements(array_rand($source_array, $number, $source_array));
```

But I didn't find any such function(s) in the manual nor in googling. Am I overlooking the obvious?

Comment: What's wrong with writing your own function for it?

Comment: Nothing's wrong per se; I was just thinking that I had to be re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I don't think you are overlooking anything.  If you want to be able to do it in one line, write a function that will help you do so.

Comment: @llama if you post that as an answer I will upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution would be to shuffle the array and return a slice from the start of it.

Or, if you don't want to alter the array, you could do:

```
array_intersect_key($source_array, array_combine(
    array_rand($source_array, $number), range(1, $number)));
```

This is a bit hacky because `array_intersect` can work on keys or values, but not selecting keys from one array that match values in another. So, I need to use `array_combine` to turn those values into keys of another array.

Answer (score 2):

What about usung `array_flip`? Just came to my mind:

```
$random_elements =  array_rand(array_flip($source_array), 3);
```

First we flip the array making its values become keys, and then use `array_rand`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, not tested!!!

> array_walk(array_rand($array, 2), create_function('&$value,$key',
>   '$value = '.$array[$value].';'));